# ManyToOne relationship with non-persistent entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I want to know if you can make a connection to an entity other than Hibernate or if there is any way to simulate it in code. Something like this:

Main class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "marter_table")
public class MasterEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")      
    private Integer id;

    //@ManyToOne ??
    //@JoinColumn(name = "??", nullable = false)???
    private Foo foo;

    //Getters & setters
}
```

Related class:

```
public class Foo {

    private String code;

    private String name;

    //Getters & setters
}
```

Dao:

```
//DAO
@Component
public class FooDAOImpl implements FooDAO {

    private static Map<String, Foo> FOO = null;


    private final void initFoo() {
        FOO = new HashMap<String, Foo>();

        Foo f1 = new Foo("1", "foo1");
        Foo f2 = new Foo("2", "foo2");
        Foo f3 = new Foo("3", "foo3");

        FOO.put("1", f1);
        FOO.put("1", f2);
        FOO.put("3", f3);
    }

    public final List<Fii> getAll(){

        List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        if (FOO == null) {
            initFoo();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Foo> e : FOO.entrySet()) {
           fooList.add(e.getValue());
        }

        return fooList;
    };  

    public final Foo getByCode(String code) {
        if (FOO == null) {
            initFoo();
        }

        return FOO.get(code);
    };
}
```

You can make a ManyToOne with the Foo class? Or make persistent if he recovers database, simply by setting it through code.

Any other solution to make a relationship with an entity that is not retrieved from a database.

Comment: sorry, but you are going to have to implement this your self. Hibernate is primarily concerned with JPA-mapped Entities. It cannot know anything about some classes that you have created in memory. If you show the code for your Master DAO, then I can probably suggest a way you can implement this.

Comment: For a start, you need to map a `@Column` in `MasterEntity` to the `foo_code` column you mention below. Then you're going to define a `@Transient` for your `private Foo foo`, as Eslaron suggested. But that's only the start of it. Wherever you are loading a `MasterEntity` from the database, you need to use your `FooDAO` to find the correponding `Foo` for each `MasterEntity` and set the reference to it.

Comment: Is there any way to create a fictitious entity persisted to make ManyToOne relationship?

Comment: Not with JPA/Hibernate. You have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try marking your non-persistent entity with @Transient annotation.

```
@Transient
private Foo foo;
```

That way Hibernate should ignore it and stop trying to persist it.

Comment: But the MasterEntity table would have a foo_code column to map the Foo class. How would you map for the class with the values implemented by code? Can you do that? Obviously without any referential integrity.